# Cast IQueryable generic to another IQueryable generic

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, generics

I would like to have a common class for my business layers (BL) which has a method convert IQueryable to IQueryable.
- efo: Entity Framework object
- bo: business object

I'm using Entity Framework Core.

```
public partial class Language //EF object
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Image { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<News> News { get; set; }
}

public class BOLanguage //Business object
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Image { get; set; }
}

public class BL<efo, bo>
       where efo : class, new()
       where bo : class, new()
{
    public Context context;
    public BL()
    {
        context = new Context();
    }

    public IQueryable<bo> SelectAll()
    {
        IQueryable<efo> query = context.Set<efo>();
        return query.Select(x => new bo
        {
           //TODO: I don't know how to do here 
        });;
    }

    //public IQueryable<BOLanguage> SelectAll() //example
    //{
    //    return context.Language.Select(x => new BOLanguage
    //    {
    //        Name = x.Name,
    //        Image = x.Image
    //    });
    //}
}
```

Thank you. Hope you understand.

Comment: automapper can help with this sort of scenario.

Comment: @DanielA.White many thanks. it works for me. you saved my day.